# How do I calculate a number if its number of factors (N) and number of prime factors (K) are given?

Tags: math, numbers, primes, prime-factoring, number-theory

How do I calculate a number if its number of factors (N) and number of prime factors (K) are given?

**Example**: if `N = 4` and `K = 2` is given then the only possible value will be `6`

**Explanation** : of the above is 6 has 4 factors (1,2,3,6) of which 2 are primes (2,3). So the only possible value is 6.

Comment: Notice that for N = 4 and K = 2 you could also get 10 -> 1, 2, 5, 10. Do you need uniqueness or just find a valid number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.I suggest you to kindly try to code for the above problem and whenever you face a problem post your **code** along with the problem you face. Read this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to get an idea on how to post question.

Comment: there can be many such numbers potentially, including none.

Comment: @MohammedShabeerkp i want to code this problem but unable to get the approach.

Comment: `numfactors(num) = PRODUCT { (1+i) FOR (p,i) IN prime_factorization(num) }` where e.g. `prime_factorization(18) = { (2,1) , (3,2) }` because `18 == 2^1 * 3^2`. start from here. understand why that formula is true, and you'll be able to solve it. ---- a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61026482/849891) was also recently asked.

Comment: @mgostIH you are right, its okay if there is no such number for a given pair but what if there exist such number then how to find it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark its about programming

Comment: @MohammedShabeerkp please take a look at the code

Comment: @WillNess , i have added the code please take a look at  this

Comment: I suspect OP is trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054171/time-limit-excedeed-error-for-large-values/61057036#61057036) and asked the wrong question here (how to find a number with N factors and K prime factors) when the question they are actually trying to solve is whether such a number exists, not to produce such a number (although producing one, if any exist, is fairly simple).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil There are at least three similar questions in the last day - perhaps online contest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any integer number can be represented as product of powers of primes:

```
I = 2^p1 * 3^p2 * 5^p3 * 7^p4 * 11^p5 * ....
```

Total number of all its factors is

```
N = (p1+1) * (p2+1) * (p3+1) * ....
     \__________________________/ 
            K multipliers
```

So you you need to represent the value `N` as a product of `K` factors larger than 1.

Factorize N into primes, group these primes into K groups.

Imagine you have `N=420` with 5 prime factors: `2 2 3 5 7` and `K=3`. Make groups `2*2, 3*5, 7` (or any other combination) so corresponding powers to make `I` are `3,14,6`

For example, having `N = 12` and `K=3`, you can represent `12 = 2 * 2 * 3` and use a product of any two primes with a square of a third prime as the number `I`. The smallest such value is `60 (2^2 * 3 * 5)`, the next one is `90 (2 * 3^2 * 5)` and so on (for example, `3 * 7 * 11^2` is also a solution).

For the case `N = 12` and `K=2` you can represent `12 = 3 * 4` and get results as `p^2*q^3` or `12 = 2 * 6` and get results as `p*q^5` where `p,q` are distinct primes

For the case `N = 12` and `K=4` you cannot  represent `12` as product of four integers larger than `1`, so it is impossible to produce result with these arguments

Comment: maybe also include the  N=12 , K=2 (and K=4) cases in the answer, for completeness?

Comment: @Alex Ed Code is completely wrong. Factorize N into primes, group these primes into K groups.

Comment: *Now* it's a proper answer! :)

Comment: @MBo i have factorized the N but, how to group them. can you please give an example

Comment: Imagine you have 5 prime factors of N-420:  `2 2 3 5 7` and K=3. Make groups `2*2, 3*5, 7` (or any other combination) so corresponding powers to make `I` are `3,14,6`